# What are the hyperparameters values searched with H2O Automl?

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o

I'm curious. Do we know the ranges of the hyperparameters searched in H2O AutoML ?

I checked this link http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html that provides the list of hyperparameters searched for each model but the ranges are not specified.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available (yet) in the H2O User Guide, but we have a ticket [open](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-6799) to add it.  In the ticket, there is a link to the `AutoML.java` file which contains this information.